# How to deal status codes with angular2?

Tags: angular, http, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I am new to angular 2 and trying to learning it .I am working on a website where the responses are coming from backend api with two scenarios .

**1 - Success response - 200 - status code**

**2 - Error response - 400 - status code**

Below is the response i am getting from backend.

1).

```
{"message":{
       "message":"Permission already exist.",
        "statusCode":400
    }}
```

2).

```
 {
      "message":{
        "message":"Record successfully inserted ",
        "statusCode":200
     }
   }
```

But when ever i am getting response as error with 400 status code , It is calling as success function in my components. Below the total code for the success and error message . ***If my below response format is correct-way, then what is the mistake that not calling error in error function***.

**Service.ts**

```
 create(data): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.config.STORE_KEY +  '/public/api/role/create/' + this.userDetails.roleid , data)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      // ...errors if any
      .catch((error: any) => {
                if (error.status <= 400 ||  error.status ===500) {
                    return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
                }
            });
  }
```

**component.ts**

```
this.roleService.createRole(requestFormat).subscribe(suc => this.roleSuccess(suc),
             err => this.roleEroor(err));

roleSuccess(suc) {
console.log('sucess')
}

roleEroor(error) {
console.log('error')
}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Hello sir. if you are not able to give answer then please don't give negative point. You do not know how much important is this topic. If you are not understand question just ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, I think your backend is always returning an HTTP 200 (OK) response, and it simply includes a "statusCode" property in the response body with a different code depending on the situation.

That is definitely a bad practice, as in case of error in should return an HTTP 400 response, not a 200 with some other way of conveying the error in the body.
To check if I am right, either inspect the HTTP response from the backed, or try changing your code to this:

```
create(data): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.config.STORE_KEY +  '/public/api/role/create/' + this.userDetails.roleid , data)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .map((response: any) => {
               if (response.message.statusCode >= 300) {
                    return Observable.throw(new Error(response.message.statusCode));
                }
                return response;
       });
 }
```

Note that if this works as you expect it, it means the backed has a poor implementation. If you created the backed, then I suggest you change it, otherwise get in contact with whoever developed it.

Comment: even it's coming my sucess function

Comment: can you please provide any example what is the format for backend api respoces for sucess and error

Comment: can you do a console.log(response) inside the second map function from my example, and let me know the output?

Comment: {"message":{"message":"Permission already exist.","status_code":400}}

Comment: from other api I observed that whenevenr status code 400 is comping it's shows red color in console, but in this above scenario I am getting block color

Comment: Ok, the problem is indeed what I suspected, just that the status code property in the body is spelled differently. Try the code below, and please mark my answer if this was helpful:

Comment: `create(data): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.config.STORE_KEY +  '/public/api/role/create/' + this.userDetails.roleid , data)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .map((response: any) => {
               if (response.message.status_code >= 300) {
                    return Observable.throw(new Error(response.message.status_code));
                }
                return response;
       });
 }`